# iOS Auto login WKWebView using Google Sign In (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, wkwebview, google-signin

I have a Web View app for iOS and using only Web View, In some pages sign-in is required for that i am using Google Sign-in that is working find but i want to auto-login via google every time once user login successfully.
Is it possible to skip sign-in / auto login while on application next time after once login?